# Python Excel Highlight Cell Differences

Tags: python, excel, highlight, difference

preface:  I'm new and self taught.  This is my first coding project.  I know it's terrible.  I'm going to rewrite it once it's complete and working.

I'm trying to write a python script that will compare 2 excel files and highlight the cells that are different.  I can print out the differences (using pandas) and highlight a cell (only by hard coding a specific cell).  I can't figure out how to highlight cells based on the printed out differences.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(mxln)  # Loads master xlsx for comparison
df2 = pd.read_excel(sfcn)  # Loads student xlsx for comparison
print('If NaN, correct.  If not NaN, incorrect')
difference = df2[df2 != df1]  # Scans for differences
print(difference)

lmfh = load_workbook(mxln)  # Load mxln for highlight
lsfh = load_workbook(sfcn)  # Load sfcn for highlight
lmws = lmfh.active
lsws = lsfh.active

redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFEE1111', end_color='FFEE1111', fill_type='solid')
lsws['A1'].fill = redFill  #  Hardcoded cell color
lsfh.save(sfcn)
```

This is only the part of the code I'm stuck on.  I can post the rest if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the style to add highlighting to your dataframe in pandas.

```
df2.style.apply(highlight_differences)
```

Then you can write a function which sets the highlighting criteria

```
def highlight_differences():
    # check for differences here
    return ['background-color: yellow']
```